# Will counting in file (PHP) result in clients receiving same number?

Tags: php

I'm creating a small classroom-app website, where students will be logging in with a random generated code which the teacher will give them. I need every student to have a unique code so I'm using the following script

```
$count = file_get_contents($classcode . "/count.txt");
$count = $count + 1;
file_put_contents($classcode . "/count.txt", $count);
```

Now my question is, will clients be able to receive the same value for `$count` if they load up the page simultaneously? And maybe anyone has an better way to do such thing?

Comment: Why not use a database?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc the program it self is really small, setting up a database seems unnecessary to me. There should be other ways (like above), and wouldn't it raise the same question? Getting the number out of a database is almost the same as getting it out of a file, right?

Comment: You can create a random string on each login ?

Comment: TXT can be manually altered, are vulnerable to data corruption, can be polluted, demands extra logics and a lot of headache to work queries, statements, procedures, data fetching of any kind... It's about changing the scope to evade problems that can be evaded. Just look at the trouble you're getting just to produce primary keys while a DB would do the dirty work for you with handful of security and availability.

Comment: I highly recommend SQLite.

Comment: It would be much better for the application in general to use a database because you can not narrow down results by query when you are grabbing from a file. Also if you go down this path and you are then asked to do a page that summarizes all the codes or something, you have loop through folders and such and such, it will be a pain...you will ask yourself why you didn't do a database in the first place...

Comment: Those above are the answers to your question *And maybe anyone has an better way to do such thing?* --> **definitively a database**.

Comment: well the only thing they need is a number.. and doing that in order is the easiest since the teacher client can read the file as well and display the amount of students connected.. a database for just a number?..

Comment: @AlanMachado actually my main question was if it would be possible using the script above for clients to get the same number, I would be really interested to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the file [can be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479580/is-there-a-risk-in-running-file-put-contents-on-the-same-file-from-different-p) unless you lock it

```
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Documentation: [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.file-get-contents.php)

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899737/should-lock-ex-on-both-read-write-be-atomic) - file_get_contents does not respect file locking

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem, you're just making sure they do not write at the same time. The reading part is the most essential, and they will still read the same value.

Comment: They will, yes. That's why files are not used to store data. At most, SQLite databases are.