# How to set an expiry for a cache file?

Tags: php, file, caching, cache-control

I am wondering how cache systems like doctrine-cache or zend-cache, set an expiry for cache files if those files are not in /tmp folder. How is possible to set an expiry for cache files? If I want to use my own cache file system with php rather than using doctrine or zend, how can I set an expiry for it if I don't want to place it in /tmp folder?

Answer (score 2):

The cache is pretty simple. Let's say you have directory `cache`. 
You set expiration time for files which are there under variable `$expire`

So the algorithm is

```
$file = "cache/cached.jpg";
$expire = 60 * 3600;

if (filectime($file) > time() + $expire)
{
   // reload file and invalidate cache
} else if (file_exists($file){
   // get from cache
} else {
  // get file and save it to cache then return  
}
```

but it's better to use caches that are there like http cache etc with expire header, varnish etc.

Comment: Actually I want to use it for a .dat ir .txt file, not a page, so is it still possible to use http cache as you said? In your sample cache expires after 60 hours? For .txt file still better to use filectime rather than filemtime? @Robert

Comment: yes it is possible to do by webserver for example in apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using cache service as [Memcached](https://memcached.org/). There is a [third parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) to a **set** function, which means number of seconds after which the value will expire.

Comment: I know about in memory cache systems. But here my question is about file cache. Anyway, I still vote up for you.

Comment: Oh. Then I think you must program the logic of expiring by yourself. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262857/5-minute-file-cache-in-php

Comment: As suggested in that link how to lock with rename()? It locks sutomatically or which parameter should I pass to lock? @Wax Cage

Comment: I dont understand file locking too much, but this answer seem to explain it a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899737/should-lock-ex-on-both-read-write-be-atomic/4899822#4899822

Comment: Maybe I would personally recommend, if you are building a php component like for your framework or so, to not let any other processes to modify your cached files and just script your own application locking (where each time you want to use a cache file, you must check the lock).