# flock() between PHP and C edge case

Tags: php, c, c++11, flock

I have a PHP script which receives and saves invoices as files in Linux. Later, a C++ infinite loop based program reads each and does some processing. I want the latter to read each file safely (only after fully written).

PHP side code simplification:

```
file_put_contents("sampleDir/invoice.xml", "contents", LOCK_EX)
```

On the C++ side (with C filesystem API), I must first note that I want to preserve a code which deletes the files in the designated invoices folder which are empty, just as a means to properly deal with the edge case of an empty file being created from other sources (not the PHP script).

Now, here's a C++ side code simplification, too:

```
FILE* pInvoiceFile = fopen("sampleDir/invoice.xml", "r");

if (pInvoiceFile != NULL)
{
    if (flock(pInvoiceFile->_fileno, LOCK_SH) == 0)
    {
        struct stat fileStat;
        fstat(pInvoiceFile->_fileno, &fileStat);
        string invoice;
        invoice.resize(fileStat.st_size);

        if (fread((char*)invoice.data(), 1, fileStat.st_size, pInvoiceFile) < 1)
        {
            remove("sampleDir/invoice.xml"); // Edge case resolution
        }

        flock(pInvoiceFile->_fileno, LOCK_UN);
    }
}

fclose(pInvoiceFile);
```

As you can see, the summarizing key concept is the cooperation of `LOCK_EX` and `LOCK_SH` flags.

My problem is that, while this integration has been working fine, yesterday I noticed the edge case executed for an invoice which should not be empty, and thus it got deleted by the C++ program.

PHP manual on [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) mentions the following for the `LOCK_EX` flag:

> Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing. In other words, a **`flock()` call happens between the `fopen()` call and the `fwrite()` call**. This is not identical to an `fopen()` call with mode `"x"`.

- Could the problem be caused as a race condition by the `LOCK_EX` not being established right before `file_put_contents` calls `fopen`? If so, what could be done to solve this while keeping the edge case removal code?
- Otherwise, may I be doing anything wrong overall?

Comment: Does your code run on Linux?

Comment: Yes, both divides run concretely on a CentOS 7, 64-bit system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is assuming that the `file_put_contents()` operation is atomic, and that using `FLOCK_EX` and `FLOCK_SH` is enough to ensure no race conditions between the two programs happen. [This is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899822/3889449).

As you can see from the PHP doc, the `FLOCK_EX` is applied *after* opening the file. This is important, because it leaves a short window of time for the C++ program to successfully open the file and lock it with `FLOCK_SH`. At that point the file was already truncated by the `fopen()` done by PHP, and it's empty.

What's most likely happening is:

1. PHP code opens the file for writing, truncating it and effectively wiping out its content.
2. C++ code opens the file for reading.
3. C++ code requests the shared lock on the file: the lock is granted.
4. PHP code requests the exclusive lock on the file: the call blocks, waiting for the lock to be available.
5. C++ code reads the file's contents: nothing, the file is empty.
6. C++ code deletes the file.
7. C++ code releases the shared lock.
8. PHP code acquires the exclusive lock.
9. PHP code writes to the file: the data does not reach the disk because the inode associated with the open file descriptor does not exist anymore.
10. You are effectively left with no file and the data is lost.

The problem with your code is that the operations you are doing on the file from two different programs are not atomic, and the way you are acquiring the locks does not help in ensuring that those don't overlap.

The only sane way of guaranteeing the atomicity of such an operation on a POSIX compliant system, without even worrying about file locking, is to take advantage of the atomicity of [`rename(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html):

> If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access `newpath` will find it missing.
>
> If `newpath` exists but the operation fails for some reason, `rename()` guarantees to leave an instance of `newpath` in place.

The equivalent [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) PHP function is what you should use in this case. It's the simplest way to guarantee atomic updates to a file.

What I would suggest is the following:

- PHP code:

  ```php
  $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "myprefix");     // Create a temporary file.
  file_put_contents($tmpfname, "contents");    // Write to the temporary file.
  rename($tmpfname, "sampleDir/invoice.xml");  // Atomically replace the contents of invoice.xml by renaming the file.

  // TODO: check for errors in all the above calls, most importantly tempnam().
  ```
- C++ code:

  ```cpp
  FILE* pInvoiceFile = fopen("sampleDir/invoice.xml", "r");

  if (pInvoiceFile != NULL)
  {
      struct stat fileStat;
      fstat(fileno(pInvoiceFile), &fileStat);

      string invoice;
      invoice.resize(fileStat.st_size);

      size_t n = fread(&invoice[0], 1, fileStat.st_size, pInvoiceFile);
      fclose(pInvoiceFile);

      if (n == 0)
          remove("sampleDir/invoice.xml");
  }
  ```

This way, the C++ program will always either see the old version of the file (if `fopen()` happens before PHP's `rename()`) or the new version of the file (if `fopen()` happens after), but it will never see an inconsistent version of the file.

Comment: Hey, sorry to revive this old topic. Originally I thought your answer was perfect, but it turns out after all this time happened and having been running your solution, I've had a case of "0 bytes read" again from the C++ end, causing the invoice file to be deleted and lost (we aren't in production yet, luckily). From the latest info I have read (including your answer), `rename()` only performs atomic updates to the file. I could have assumed wrong all the time. The affected case involved a new invoice creation - I need atomicity always. Does it mean creation isn't atomic, then? Thanks

Comment: @Adrián I guess you should post another more detailed question if your problem is different than the one in this question (maybe reference this one). Renaming is the only thing that is atomic for a file in Linux. If you want atomic creation, the only way to do it is by (1) creating a file with another name (2) writing everything to it and closing it (3) renaming it to the real name you want. That way, you will see the new file appear atomically with all the content inside of it.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering whether to make a new question or not. But if you confirm that atomic creation is possible that way, I trust so. Possibly my real PHP implementation, which currently relies on a XML API to write the temporary file maybe doesn't close it before renaming and it has something to do, that's about the only reason I can think of. However, I started taking a different way by using a more manual approach, which is portable at least. Wish me luck!

Comment: @Adrián I would *strongly* suggest using a real database for this though. Using random files and moving them around is really the clumsiest solution to the problem, you would definitely not want something like that in a real production server.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of this common recommendation but my boss always talked about using files so we're fine with the design (and I'm as long as system stays protect against race conditions as such)